# Остановить выполнение сценария на странице

Tags: javascript

При получении ошибки появляется "окно"(организованно div-ами) с просьбой перезагрузить страницу (организованно через try...catch), но сценарий не останавливается и продолжает выполнение(посылая запросы на сервер). Есть ли способ полностью остановить(заморозить) выполнение сценария на странице?

Answer (score 0):

Вот краткий пример:

```
<script>
try {
    alert("Входим");
    try {
        alert("Тут Ваш код");
        throw "Ошибка";
    } catch(e) {
        alert(e);
        throw "stop"; // скрипт дальше не выполниться.
    }
    //этот блок уже не выполнится
    alert("Меня никто не увидит(((");
} catch(e){}
</script>
```

Comment: Это мне не помогло, к сожалению... Решила свою проблему иначе... Ввела глобальную переменную и всё что требовалось остановить при ошибке обернула в условие.